# Space on either side of UITableView in iPhone 7 plus simulator

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uitableview, xcode8

I have a tableview inside of a view in a view controller, and for some reason on the iPhone 7 plus simulator, there are blank margins on either side of it. This doesn't happen for any other simulator, and doesn't happen for TableViewControllers. Is there a way to get rid of this?

[image]

Comment: If you're creating this in a storyboard, be sure to uncheck the "Constrain to margins" checkbox when adding constraints. I don't know for sure if that's the issue, but it's something to try.

Comment: @keithbhunter that is unchecked.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I have the same issue!

Comment: @NateBirkholz No, I never did. If you find out, please let me know!

Comment: @EthanZhao I changed the constraints in InterfaceBuilder to be wider to solve it. There seemed to be no other way. So instead of `Trailing Space to Superview == -16.0/Leading Space to Superview == -16.0`, I made them `-20.0` and moved the UI elements in slightly to compensate. There doesn't seem to be an elegant way to detect the "plus" size class. This is a workaround and not a solution, unfortunately.

Comment: @NateBirkholz Hm, I see. But if there's no way to detect the "plus" size class, then for all other devices other than iphone 7+ the table is going to be slightly larger than the screen, right?

Comment: @EthanZhao correct, it will be slightly wider than the screen on other devices. I don't like the solution much but I hated the gap on the larger devices. In practice on my iPhone 6 it isn't noticeable that it is larger than the screen. I think another solution of course is to create the tableView programmatically instead of in Interface Builder and set `self.view = self.tableView` which is why i think this works when the root VC's class is UITableViewController.

Answer (score 0):

I think You were setting autolayout this way shown below in image:

[image]

Instead of above, Do your autolayout below way as shown in image:

[image]

Hope it helps you,

Thanks

Comment: it is set that way.